# How to use inversify js along with overnight js?

Tags: typescript, express

I'm playing with expressJS and especially interested in figuring out how to set up a server class.
Currently I've written this (toy stuff):

```
export class ApplicationServer extends Server {

    constructor(public config: IServerConfig) {
        super(config.enableLogging);
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
        this.setUpControllers();
    }

    private setUpControllers(): void {
        super.addControllers([...controllers].map( (controller) => new controller()));
    }

    public async start(): Promise<void> {
        this.app.get(
            '*',
            (_: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
                res.send(`Server started on port: ${this.config.port}`);
            }
        );

        if (this.config.enableLogging) {
            this.app.listen(
                this.config.port,
                () => Logger.Imp(`Server is listening on port: ${this.config.port}`)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Then I started setting up DI with the help of inversityJS but faced the problem with the `setUpControllers` function that map-instantiates the available controllers. I understand it should be managed through a special DI container and I've already set up one but what I don't understand yet is how to manage the instantiation logic here.

I would appreciate your help.

EDIT:

I've just found this: https://github.com/inversify/inversify-express-utils

Seems like it's a usable lib but does it mean that I have to get rid of overnightJS in my code? On top of that, I'm not sure if the lib is still alive and kicking...is it supported? It doesn't look like it's used a lot. But I don't get how it is possible to build an application without the DI nowadays...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super familiar with inversify but you wouldn't be able to use it with the Server constructor. You could create another wrapper class around Server. In there, import the server class, instantiate it, and call server.start() inside the class that's using inversify.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I'm the creator of OvernightJS. No, I'm no longer maintaining this library. I've evolved beyond object-oriented programming. Please see `express-generator-typescript` if you wanted to see an example of modern procedural-programming with express.